# Problems allocating memory for structure

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following main function which declares a World structure and reads data from a Xml file, which is stored in the structure:

```
int main(){
    World *w;
    w = create_world();
    world_load("xmlfile", w);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The memory for the World structure is allocated by calling the function create_world():

```
World *create_world(){
    World *w = NULL;
    if(!(w = (World *)malloc(sizeof (World)))) return NULL;

    return w;
}
```

The World structure is the following:

```
struct _World {
        Space *space[MAX_SPACES + 1];
        Object *object[MAX_OBJECTS + 1];
        Link *link[MAX_LINKS + 1];
        Player *player;
};
```

When I execute the program, a segmentation fault occurs. I've tried passing valgrind and it keep reporting that a "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value". It may be obvious, but I just can't figure out what is the problem... Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*a segmentation fault occurs*" on which line of your sources? Also which source file line does Valgrind log for this message "*"Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value"*"

Comment: Does `main()` know about how `World *create_world()` is declared, prototyped? Or does your code leave it to the linker to get to know each other closer?

Comment: @alk The seg fault occurs in another function. I've tracked the origin of the problem with valgrind and it seems to be in the allocation. Then it drags the problem until the program crashes. In main I've included the header that includes the prototype of World *create_world()

Comment: Also prior to the (micro-)optmisation phase, you might like to use `calloc()` to fetch memory, as it initialises it to all zeros, which could significantly help to avoid misunderstanding by code using this memory.

Comment: "*I've tracked the origin of the problem with valgrind*" providing the exact line of code (plus surrounding) might be very helpful for someone trying to help you with exactly **this** code. Showing the Valgrind log would also be very helpful.

Comment: OT: Btw, it shall be `int main(void)` at least.

Comment: @alk I know, but I don't understand why it says the variable is uninitialised...

Comment: "*the variable is uninitialised*": Dear userXYZ, please what are you talking about? Probably because it hadn't been initilaised? Please see my comment on using `calloc()` but `malloc()` above.

Comment: @alk I'm sorry, I hadn't seen your previous comment about calloc(). I've already tried, but the problem remains

Comment: So take your time and collect any necessary information needed for a proper error/trouble report, then come back here and add it as an update to your answer and we'll see.

Comment: could you post the world_load() definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are using the fields of your World struct without actually initializing them.  Since those fields are only pointers, they are not allocated when you allocate memory for your World object.  This would result in an access violation when accessing w->space[0].  You should either allocate the memory for your arrays, or remove the pointer notation from your arrays in the World struct, depending on how the fields are used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure that's the problem. I allocate memory for the pointers one by one when I need them,so that when I access w->space[0], I've allocated memory for it yet

Comment: I was looking closer to the code and the error was exactly that one, but it was in another function and had nothing to do with the allocations. Thanks again